# Power a servo momentarily using a capacitor for geocaching

Tags: capacitor, servo, windturbine

I'm trying to build a cache for geocaching based on a movie - [*The Boy Who Harnessed the Wind*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7533152/)

Those who don't know what geocaching is, please visit [here.](https://www.geocaching.com) It is a fun activity.

I have this idea for a cache.

Using a toy windmill (like those found on [Banggood](https://www.banggood.com/DC-Micro-Motor-Small-LED-Lights-Vertical-Axis-Wind-Generator-Wind-Turbines-Blades-p-1277416.html?cur_warehouse=CN&rmmds=mywishlist) or [Aliexpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32814070202.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.6d044c4dZhpnb7) for learning purposes) that can power an LED,  the geocacher would (using a balloon, not just blowing to it), by blowing wind,  generate some power, that the capacitor would store and when reaching the power needed, discharge it to activate a small servo (and the arduino connected to it) that would open the door to the logbook.

Would this be something feasible? Can a capacitor do such thing or is there a better option?

Values for the hobby windmill dc micro motor (according to the vendor):

- voltage: 0.01 to 5.5v
- Current: 0.01 to 100mA

The Servo would be a hobby one, like a SG90 or MG90s

Comment: A capacitor can store energy. The problem is you need to know how much energy your servo needs to know how much capacitance you need and then you need to know how much energy the turbine can generate in a given time to know how long you need to rotate it to generate enough energy for the system you intend to run for a given time. As there is no values for power generation or consumption, we can't guess how long you need to use the windmill to activate your servo, and feasibily is defined by you.

Comment: Thanks @Justme . I've added the values to the question

Comment: Thank you @Drew ! Keep it simple and a Gearmotor or a solenoid might do that ! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will probably be much simpler to use a solenoid, doorlock plunger or gearmotor that simply moves when power is applied.

Those will run gracefully on intermediate voltages that the windmill might generate.